# LoggingInInterceptor in Apache CXF

Tags: java, apache, rest, cxf, interceptor

I  have to write a CustomLogger at interceptor level and I was referring to LoggingInInterceptor code in Apache CXF. I see that in the code, it is first getting the input stream from the message and then later its setting it back to the message.

Please refer below code and url for the same:

```
// restore the delegating input stream or the input stream 
   if (is instanceof DelegatingInputStream) { 
        ((DelegatingInputStream)is).setInputStream(bis); 
   } else { 
        **message.setContent(InputStream.class, bis);** 
   }
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-api/2.7.4/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/LoggingInInterceptor.java#152

Can you please let me know why this is being done even though we are not changing input stream here. It will be really helpful if detailed description is given for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The input stream actually is changed. Logging will "consume" its bytes and the stream will be set to end after that. Which makes it unusable for following message handlers. Therefore the interceptor copies the bytes first to keep them in memory, then uses them in a new input stream and gives following interceptors access in another new input stream (which is not possible with actual http input stream but is with the bytes in memory).